# I Can't point to to MSClient in library in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, azure

why can't the MSClient find the MSClient header file!?

```
static let sharedClient = MSClient(applicationURLString: "http://<mysite>.azurewebsites.net")
```

I have added the MicrosoftAzureMobile in the "Link Binary With Libraries" in the Xcode project. I've tried to clean the project and restarting the Xcode.
The end goal is to make my project mimic the projects that Azure produces when a user create an push notification app service per the 2nd picture but tonight that download is not working! It throws 500 Internal error. It was working yesterday but not today.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced this issue again last night... I've tried numerous times of cleaning and restarting. But I solved it at the end. I don't remember if at the time of posting that question, if I had the header bridge setup or not; that bridging step is necessary.
Also, there is a more proper way of adding a framework. It must be copied and pasted manually in your project tree structure and then added via the Build Phases and then referenced accordingly by the bridging header file via the Swift Compiles - Code Generation => Objective-C Bridging Header in the Build Settings.